# FTP user without access to other folders

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, ftp, user-permissions

I'm a newbie with FTP/User permissions. I have a domain and a dedicated server. 
Lets say my domain is `www.mysite.com`
All my files are inside httpd folder.

I'd like to create a folder for a new user inside httpd, 
for example `/newuser`. The user should be able to access his files from browser `www.mysite.com/newuser` but this folder should be the root for him.

Ideally he can only upload files onto this folder, with no permission to view files outside this folder. Is this possible.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which FTP daemon are you running? Quite a few will support chrooted environments without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a 'lock user to home folder' option you can set to prevent the user from browsing outside of his home directory. You'll just have to look where to enable that - usually when you setup a user account.